# can't see completed payment in PayPal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

we test our application on PayPal sandbox.
I was able to make payment form one account (ewa.tkacz@zoho.com) to another (ewa.tkacz-facilitator@mmigroup.pl), and status of this payment is completed on payer account (payment ID 3F335538TV000622E), but on receiver business account I can't see this payment and can't get it by API.

[image: payer account]

[image: receiver account]

This question is to PayPal, as You recommend to ask on Your forum on Stackoverflow, however if anyone faced similar issue, please vote or response.
I don't believe in what I see; it seems I make some stupid mistake... I wasn't able to find any such issue on Google, here and in PayPal technical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed both test accounts and I see transaction 3F335538TV000622E (buyer transaction ID)/28A51825L7124154N (seller transaction ID) appearing correctly. There is a difference in the date for the two payments due to the default timezone for the accounts. Based on your screenshots, you are seeing the correct information as the transaction would show on 6/3/14 in the ewa.tkacz-facilitator@mmigroup.pl as it defaults to PDT and 6/4/14 in the ewa.tkacz@zoho.com which defaults to BST.

Comment: OK, thank You very much... I felt that this is the stupid question :) but I was confused by different unique transaction ids - I assumed that they are the same for both PayPal accounts.